# how to set filename that contains variable in powershell

Tags: powershell

i need to output Get-ChildItem cmdlet into file, which name contains current date.
this is what is tried:

```
Get-Date -OutVariable date
Get-ChildItem > $date.txt
```

powershell doesn't print any error messsages, but there's no file created.

i need to do some equivalent to the following line in windows cmd

```
dir > %date%.txt
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd' -OutVariable date
Get-ChildItem | Out-File ".\$date.txt"
```

Keep in mind that `Get-Date`, by default, will include the time component, as well; which can contain colons (:) -- depending upon your regional time-formatting preferences -- which is an invalid character for filenames.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it did! thanks a lot!! i should have tried tinkering with quotes. Get-Date -OutVariable date
Get-ChildItem > ".\$date.txt" also works